# How to improve the precision of matrix calculation in Matlab or Python?

Tags: precision, matrix-multiplication

Now, I have a matrix `S`, and it satisfies the recursion relation:

`S_{m,n}=(1+|α|^2)S_{m-1,n-1}+(m-1)(n-1)S_{m-2,n-2}+α(m-1)S_{m-2,n-1}+α*(n-1)S_{m-1,n-2}`

`S_{0,n}=(α*)^n and S_{n,0}=α^n`

Obviously, when `|α|>>1`, the matrix becomes an ill-matrix, but the matrix is reversible.

However, when I use the matlab to calculate its inverse matrix `S^{-1}`, I find `S^{-1}S≠I`.
In other words, when I do some matrix multiplication related to the inverse matrix, the corresponding results are incorrect, or its error is non-negligible.

Actually, I need to calculate a first-order ordinary differential equation, and the equation needs the matrix and its inverse matrix (`α` is the independent variable). Therefore, I must ensure a suitable precision to obtain a correct result. Of course, the computation time must also be guaranteed; otherwise, the time taken to compute the first-order ode will be enormous.

**(Symbolic language can ensure the computation precision, but the cost is that the matrix operation time becomes very slow.)**

1. efficiently improve the precision of matrix manipulation.
2. avoid excessively long runtime of ode.